# Grouping/encapsulating related functions that are across multiple php files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on an app, and part of functionality of this app is that it is extendable through addons.

The main app uses has a `Render` class that contains a lot of static methods that have to do with output. The actual methods interact with models/views, but the basic idea is that the Render class encapsulates methods that render something, like:

```
// To output "hello"
Render::sayHello();

// To output a picture of a cat wearing a hat
Render::catWithHat();
```

Now, from time to time addons require their own unique ***output*** functions. These output functions are very similar to the `Render` methods. So...

My first thought was that it would be great if I could dynamically add methods to the `Render` class, but after reading up about on-the-fly method creation it sounds like that's generally not considered very good practice.

So then I thought, well, I could just not encapsulate the addons' render functions at all. So that you'd just call them like:

```
renderMyAddonOutput();
```

I don't love that idea either, though.

So I guess I'm just wondering what would be considered best practice for encapsulating related functions that are declared across a variety of files.

Thoughts?

Note: if it makes any difference, I'm using Laravel for this (the very latest version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a Plugin pattern where an add-on registers itself into some kind of static container on init, and then you can use PHP's magic method `__call()` or `__callStatic()` to check the plugin array when a method is called that isn't found in the base class..

So if you had:

```
Render::pluginMethod()
```

then `__callStatic()` would check your plugin registry (which can be as simple as a static array of plugin classes or methods) and if it finds that method, it calls/returns it.

Comment: Thanks! I like the sounds of this a lot! I've never heard of the "Plugin Pattern" before (especially in regards to PHP apps). Is this a generally accepted way of doing things?

Comment: I don't think it's specific to PHP, but it's just the general concept of having a method in your Render class called "registerPlugin()" or something like that, and when you have an add-on, during your app init, it calls Render::registerPlugin($this) , which then does something appropriate to your application, so that your main Render class is aware of which add-ons are available at run-time without having to hard-code the list anywhere in that main class.